# File conversion using imageMagic and Yii - unable to upload the image

Tags: php, yii, imagemagick

I am using following method to upload and convert the PDF file using image magic. The create method is working but the image is not being uploaded in the respective directory.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Alerts;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Alerts']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Alerts'];
                    $model->infoFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'infoFile');
                    $pdf_file = $model->infoFile->name;
                    $save_to = $model->getUploadPath()."sample.jpg";
        if($model->save()){
                         exec('convert "'.$pdf_file.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 800 "'.$save_to.'"', $output, $return_var);

                    }
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Could you please suggest what could be the issue.

I can assure that webserver has write permission to `$model->getUploadPath()` which is `Yii::getPathofAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';` and Image Magic is properly installed and configured in the webserver.

Comment: display `var_dump($return_var);var_dump($output);`

Comment: this is the output of var_dump($output)       221780 1421680 138724 true 603 4 <1>" [6]=> string(25) "Unknown device: pamcmyk32" [7]=> string(57) "START 661528 1578872 283058 1421680 139468 true 606 5 <2>" [8]=> string(61) "END PROCS 661528 1598968 296125 1421680 140852 true 604 5 <2>" [9]=> string(63) "gs_std_e.ps 661528 1598968 298899 1441776 145564 true 603 5 <2>" [10]=> string(63) "gs_il1_e.ps 661528 1598968 301073 1441776 145564 true 603 5 <2>" [11]=> string(68) "END FONTDIR/ENCS 661528 1598968 301199 1441776 145564 true 603 5 <2>" [12]=> string(25) "Unknown device: pamcmyk32" }

Comment: Thanks for the Var_dump, I was missing ghostscript to convert the image. after installing ghostscript everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

The exec function is disabled on most hosts for security reasons.
Can you try this to if it works ?

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs($model->getUploadPath()."sample.jpg");
```

Just to verify if the Yii way of saving files works.
If this works, you should look into:

- is exec() allowed on your server
- is Imagick correctly installed/configured

Comment: but then How I am I gonna get the image from the exec method.

Comment: and I am trying to upload the image file not the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with my Ghostscript installation. So I re-install the ghostscript and everything started to working now.  Thanks everyone for looking into matter.